# Can't Create Xtext Project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, xtext

I installed Xtext 2.12 from the Eclipse Marketplace. I'm using Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3). Following the directions in the Bettini book, I tried to create a new Xtext project, but the wizard does not appear in the New>Other... dialog. What did I miss and why doesn't stuff just work?
[image]

[image]

Comment: i cannot reproduce this. did you restart? does the error log contain any messages. if you open a "host osgi console" in console view or start eclipse with -console you can have a look if the org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.ui plugin is installed can be started

Comment: Thanks. Did restart (several times). No errors in log. No consoles to display.

Comment: Can you have a look at the Osgi console (open console view then on the arrow in the toolbar of the view. In the console view type ss Xtext.xtext.ui then type start <number you get from ss>

Comment: tried it on 2 mach. worked fine. can you try a new eclipse and install again? can you try to install from update site (http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/xtext/updates/composite/releases/) instead of market place. do you have something special on your eclipse install path (deeply nested, spaces etc - dont know if theis makes problems but who knows ...)

Comment: I do not see a place to type anything in console view; it shows only Java Stack Trace Console and Maven Console. Also, it appears that trying to install Xtext disabled other plug-ins (e.g. a JSON editor) so I can't open editors for them. I've given up on this approach. However, see  my other posts about installing Xtext for Eclipse (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46923986/xtext-bundle-org-eclipse-emf-mwe-utils-cannot-be-resolved)  and for IntelliJ (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46925180/intellij-xtext-couldnt-resolve-reference-to-grammar-org-eclipse-xtext-common-t)

Comment: Sry I fear I can’t give you further advice

Comment: Thanks. I completely deleted Eclipse and reinstalled with DSL tools. Created a new workspace. That appears to have solved the problem. Thanks again.