# Xtext Bundle org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils cannot be resolved

Tags: eclipse, xtext

I'm trying to learn to use Xtext. I was unable to create an Xtext project when I installed Xtext in an existing Eclipse Neon installation using either the marketplace or using Install New Software (see [Can't Create Xtext Project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458903/cant-create-xtext-project-in-eclipse)). I then tried installing a new Eclipse DSL Tools with the Eclipse installer. Now I can create a project, but the default project already has errors in it; I haven't even tried to edit the default project. Here are the errors:

1. In build.properties, Bundle org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils cannot be resolved.
2. In GenerateMyDsl.mwe2, A value of type 'org.eclipse.xtext.xtext.generator.XtextGenerator' can not be assigned to the feature 
   org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.AbstractCompositeWorkflowComponent.addComponent(org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.runtime.workflow.IWorkflowComponent)

I have researched these errors on Stack Overflow and elsewhere, and there are several prior instances of the same or similar errors. One suggests reloading or refreshing the target platform. Another suggests adding the mwe.utils jar to the build path. Neither of these had any effect. At this point, I am stuck. Can anybody definitively resolve this problem?

Comment: You can install mwe from the xtext update site as well

Comment: I completely deleted Eclipse and reinstalled with DSL tools. Created a new workspace. That appears to have solved the problem. Thanks.