# IntelliJ Xtext Couldn't Resolve Reference to Grammar 'org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals'

Tags: intellij-idea, xtext

I haven't had success in installing Xtext with Eclipse (see [Xtext Bundle org.eclipse.emf.mwe.utils cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46923986/xtext-bundle-org-eclipse-emf-mwe-utils-cannot-be-resolved) and [Can't Create Xtext Project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46458903/cant-create-xtext-project-in-eclipse)), so I thought I'd try IntelliJ IDEA. However, when I created the default project, I got the error "Couldn't Resolve Reference to Grammar 'org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals'". Isn't this library automatically installed with Xtext?  At this point, I am stuck. Can anybody definitively resolve this problem?

Comment: Did our double check the project has xtext facet

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work. I'm abandoning this line of attack. Thanks.